# How to hide 1 img from a 16 img loop

Tags: jquery

First time posting here so sorry if the post isn't tidy :)

I'm trying to make a 15 slide puzzle in jQuery, and my problem is this;
I'm looping 16 images and I want to hide the last image and show it after the puzzle, but it's not working, I tried using `fadeOut()` and `hide()` but it's not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    var img = "<img src='img/" + i + ".png' id="+ i +">";
    $("#board").append(img);
  }

  $("img#15").ready(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    });

  $("img").each(function() {
    var i = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
    var yAs = Math.floor(i / 4);
    var xAs = i % 4;
    $(this).data("yAs", yAs);
    $(this).data("xAs", xAs);
    var xPosition = xAs * 160;
    var yPosition = yAs * 128;
    $(this).css({"left": xPosition});
    $(this).css({"top": yPosition});
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888888;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slidepuzzle jQuery!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slidepuzzle.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="slidepuzzle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="board">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle to show your problem ?

Comment: $('#15').hide(); will hide last img. Give this in document.ready after appending all the images.

Comment: Added the snipped.

Comment: You mean like this?
`$(document).ready(function() {`

`$("#15").hide();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use  `.find()` function after appending images like that: `$("#board").find("img#15").hide();`
It happens because you append the image dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

This `$("img#15").hide();` will do the job:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    var img = "<img src='img/" + i + ".png' id="+ i +">";
    $("#board").append(img);
  }

  $("img#15").hide();

  $("img").each(function() {
    var i = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
    var yAs = Math.floor(i / 4);
    var xAs = i % 4;
    $(this).data("yAs", yAs);
    $(this).data("xAs", xAs);
    var xPosition = xAs * 160;
    var yPosition = yAs * 128;
    $(this).css({"left": xPosition});
    $(this).css({"top": yPosition});
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888888;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slidepuzzle jQuery!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slidepuzzle.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="slidepuzzle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="board">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Actually using id with just a number is a bad practice as id should be unique across the webpage and `id === 0 ... 15` has a high chance to be repeated

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to hide it with js - css will do it with

```
img:last-of-type{visibility:hidden}
```

Note that I am using visibility:hidden rather than display:none in order t preserve its spot in the DOM and flow of the page - but just hiding it from view.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    var img = "<img src='img/" + i + ".png' id="+ i +">";
    $("#board").append(img);
  }


  $("img").each(function() {
    var i = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
    var yAs = Math.floor(i / 4);
    var xAs = i % 4;
    $(this).data("yAs", yAs);
    $(this).data("xAs", xAs);
    var xPosition = xAs * 160;
    var yPosition = yAs * 128;
    $(this).css({"left": xPosition});
    $(this).css({"top": yPosition});
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #888888;
  line-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

img:last-of-type{visibility:hidden}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slidepuzzle jQuery!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slidepuzzle.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="slidepuzzle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="board">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!